# How to get Month from a date in format of YYYY/MM/DD in moment.js javascript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

If I have a date like 2014/07/28, how do I get the output to be July?

Comment: [Self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is encouraged on Stack Overflow. But, please make sure the question hasn't already been asked here. Getting the month name from a date is a very popular topic and has been asked many times.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myDateVariable= moment("2014-07-28").format("YYYY/MM/DD")
var newDateVariableMonth = moment(moment("2014-07-28").format("YYYY/MM/DD")).format('MMMM');


console.log(myDateVariable);
console.log(newDateVariableMonth);
```

**Output**

```
"2014/07/28"
"July"
```

Comment: `moment(moment("2014-07-28").format("YYYY/MM/DD")).format('MMMM');`??? why not just `moment("2014-07-28").format('MMMM');`?

Comment: Or why not myDataVariable.format('MMMM')

Comment: Hi All, appreciate your comments. This answer was specific to a project I am doing where in I need to have the date in a specific format for validation. Yes, `moment("2014-07-28").format('MMMM');` and  `myDataVariable.format('MMMM')`   Both are correct way to do instead. @JaromandaX et all thanks for pointing out.